# Puntos en ggplot2 con geom_point: relleno coloreado con transparencia y borde negro

Tags: r, ggplot2

quiero que los puntos tengan un borde negro sin alfa y que el relleno tenga alfa con color según una variable, ¿cómo puedo hacerlo? Código:

```
ggplot(data = millas, aes(x = cilindrada, y = autopista)) + 
  geom_point(aes(fill = clase),
             alpha = 0.3,
             size = 5,
             shape = 22,
             color = 'black')
```

[image: Grafico]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Primera aproximación

He trabajado con la data `iris`. En esta solución es de  [un articulo en tidyverse](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/aes_colour_fill_alpha.html) consiste en combinar dos geometrías una donde modificamos el alfa y otra donde personalizamos el color, esto lo podemos ver como si empalmáramos un las dos graficas. Una que tiene el relleno traslucido y otra con el borde opaco. Es una buena aproximación que logre, el problema para mi es que el borde opaco no se mantiene en la leyenda.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(RColorBrewer)

head(iris)


ggplot(data = iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) + 
  geom_point(color = 'black',
             size = 5,
             shape = 22)+
    geom_point(aes(fill = Species),
             alpha = 0.3,
             size = 5,
             shape = 22,
             color = 'black')
```

### Segunda aproximación

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Esta segunda aproximación consiste en crear un vector de colores personalizado. Usamos para esto el paquete `RColorBrewer` y su función `brewer.pal` pero usted podría crearlos con algún otro método, solo recuerde que el vector de colores debe tener la misma longitud de niveles de la variable que usa para `fill` (en su caso 7 para la v. clase) y también es importante que el vector de colores sea nombrado con los valores únicos de la variable `fill`.

Luego la función `alpha` que viene con `ggplot` hace los colores que usted escoja traslucidos.

El truco final lo hace `scale_fill_manual` para agregar los colores personalizados al relleno.

```
#val se crea a partir de la columna que se usa para fill
val<-unique(iris$Species)
#Se puede cambiar "Set2" para escojer otros colores, e incluso puede escojerlos manualmente de algun palette color online
col<-brewer.pal(length(val),"Set2")
col<-alpha(col,0.3)
names(col)<-val

ggplot(data = iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, fill=Species)) + 
  geom_point(size = 5,
             shape = 22,
             color = 'black')+
  scale_fill_manual(values = col)
```

Comment: muchas gracias, la segunda aproximación me funcionó a la perfección. Para la primera aproximación me ayudaron con un artículo para modificar únicamente la leyenda [aquí] (https://aosmith.rbind.io/2020/07/09/ggplot2-override-aes/?fbclid=IwAR0fnTwTO-fhOFqdmmAYAnAJNlTKC1gAaopTv_ryTdEPMiga5o7ZrKXuhPA)

Comment: Que bueno. Muy buen articulo.

Answer (score 1):

El valor de `alpha` aplica a todo el `geom_point`, es decir, sobre `fill` y `color`, para evitar esto, podemos generar una escala de colores para `fill` que incluya un valor de `alpha` específico y terminamos configurando esto por medio de `scale_fill_manual()`:

```
library(tidyverse)

colores <- alpha(c("#E69F00", "#56B4E9", "#009E73", "#F0E442", "#0072B2", "#D55E00", "#CC79A7"),
                 0.3)

ggplot(data = millas, aes(x = cilindrada, y = autopista)) + 
  geom_point(aes(fill = clase),
             size = 5,
             shape = 22) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = colores)
```

Nota: Una cosa que me desconcertó, es que los colores de los puntos no parecen coincidir con el de la leyendas, hasta que me dí cuenta la gran concentración de puntos hace que se modifiquen visualmente los colores, de hecho creo que tu gráfico incorpora algún tipo de `jitter()`.

Comment: muchas gracias, sí me funcionó esta solución pero como usted dice no coincide algunos colores con la leyenda, buscaré la solución y lo que sea el `jitter()`

Comment: Mario, el `jitter()` es una función que incorpora "ruido" random a un vector, se usa por ejemplo para que los puntos se separen un poco entre sí y que no se superpongan. Ya desde los datos debes tener algo de esto, por que guiandome por el gráfico claramente hay puntos que se acomodan en el eje de cilindros en el medio, y esta claro que los autos no tienen medio cilindro

Comment: Entendido, la utilizaré, muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

## Diagrama 5 no se logró la misma estética del libro R4DS, pero se aproximó lo más posible.

```
ggplot(data = mpg, aes(x = displ, y = hwy, color = drv)) +
```

geom_point(aes(fill = drv), alpha = 0.9, size = 3, shape = 21, color = 'white')

Libro

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ejercicio

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]